# Off-aspect conjugations

Tags: глаголы, наречия, вид

It has been confusing me the fact that a few verbs have participles which, according to textbooks, normally don't match a particular verb aspect (perfective or imperfective).

For example, **гореть** (imp.) and **сгореть** (pf.). The *past passive participle* is normally formed from the perfective aspect, however the word **горелый** exists.

Another example is **резать** (imp.), **разрезать** (pf.). According to some dictionaries, the word **резанный** exists.

Apparently there are also *past adverbs* for imperfective verbs, like **ждав** instead of **подождав**, according to cooljugator.com.

So, how far can we use *past participles* and *past adverbs* with **im**perfective verbs?

Comment: That's right, thanks for the amendment. I meant something which got burned down, like trees in a wild fire.

Comment: Additionally, *"режанный"* seems to be a typo.Did you mean [резаный](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)?

Comment: you're right once again. I transcribed it wrongly from the Толковый словарь русского языка embedded in my Mac.

Comment: That is "not a bug, but a feature". The perfective aspect denotes the completion of the process. Say, if some town... Okay, if some house burned PERFECTLY - it burned down to the ground, to the ashes, no one can use it any more. It is no more a house. That would be "сгоревший дом" - once there was a house, but no more, it perished in the perfected=completed fire. At the same time, "горелый" is imperfective, it denotes that while fire was, and it affected the house in a clearly visible way, still the destruction process was not perfected and house remains, damaged but somewhat useable still

Answer (score 2):

**Russian syntax: aspects of modern Russian syntax and vocabulary** has a good description—

-Ignore the notes (sorry, it's my personal copy)

[(F. M. Borras, Reginald Frank Christian)](https://books.google.cz/books?id=RR0ZAQAAIAAJ&dq=syntax%20of%20russian%20%20borrass&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVs5qs_KjbAhXNGewKHZYTChwQ6AEIKTAA)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikipedia article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#%D0%92_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5)  on participles doesn't emphasize the fact of past passive participles being mainly derived from perfective verbs, and in its examples lists two imperfective ones with a potential for a 3d one **печёный**

> [C]традательные причастия могут образовываться только от переходных глаголов.
>
> Причастия страдательного залога прошедшего времени образуются с
> помощью суффиксов -нн- (от глаголов на -ать: читанный, потерянный),
> -енн- (от глаголов на -ить и -чь: испеченный), -т- (от односложных глаголов: мятый).
>
> Также не от всех глаголов образуются в русском языке страдательные
> причастия прошедшего времени.

Indeed some forms of past passive participles may sound a little unusual, like **терянный**, but if context absolutely compels to using them, they can be employed and understood, for example

> Этот телефон у меня уже сто раз терянный и найденный - This phone of mine has already been about a dozen times lost and found.
>
> У меня огород 2 года стоит не копанный - My veggie garden has for
> 2 years gone non-spaded.

Considering the statement according to which past passive participles derive from transitive verbs and the list of suffixes pertaining to past participles, it appears that words formed with the suffix - **л**- (**горелый**, **спелый**, **прелый**, **лежалый**, **вялый**) can't be classed as participles.

I think they're adjectives, however indeed their link to intransitive verbs is apparent: **гнилой - гнить**, **умелый - уметь**, **усталый - устать**, **отсталый - отстать**, **запоздалый - запоздать**, **беглый - бегать**, **талый** - **таять**, **светлый - светить** (here the quality is ascribed not to the subject but to the object despite incongruence with the verb's character), and even **смелый** i believe is linked to **сметь**.

Strangely i've managed to find only [one site](http://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/5-klass/imia-prilagatelnoe-15580/polnye-i-kratkie-prilagatelnye-12418/re-81bf4f28-0c6a-43ba-82fa-b9da8363fc18) where they're mentioned and there they're listed as adjectives.

> - Прилагательные, образованные от глаголов, с суффиксом –л-. Например: обнищалый, опустелый, прошлый.

---

> *According to some dictionaries, the word резанный exists.*

My life experience confirms as much. And the phraseologism

> Орать как резанный

---

**Ждав** must be archaic and sounds awkward by modern standards. In modern language **ожидая** will be rather used instead. However it's no substitute for **подождав** due to aspect difference. Both have their use.

The [Wikipedia article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5) on past adverb states:

> несовершенный — обозначает настоящее и прошедшее времена. Образуется
> от глаголов несовершенного вида с помощью суффиксов а (-я) и отвечает
> на вопрос «что делая?»

So imperfective past adverbs derive from imperfective verbs by appendage of the -(а)я suffix and are very much in use.

Comment: So... judging by your answer, I should just ignore "ждав". But -ая is the suffix of the present adverb, if I'm not mistaken. 
So the present adverb in -ая must be taken as exclusive to imperfective verbs, while the past adverb in -в is exclusive to perfective verbs.
If it were not for your answer, I would feel tempted to ask whether ждав could be used as a replacement for the non-existent "ждая". But apparently, there's no way other than looking for a variant of the verb, like ожидать instead of ждать.

Comment: indeed, what you've named *past adverb* (apparently meaning *perfective adverbial participle*) don't have temporal aspect, only the aspect of completeness, likewise their opposites the *IMperfective adverbial participles*, therefore they are applicable to all tenses. Thus ***Они беседУЮТ, ожидая автобуса*** / ***Они беседОВАЛИ, ожидая автобуса*** / ***Они БУДУТ беседовать, ожидая автобуса*** all are grammatically correct

Comment: and vice versa ***Побеседовав, они пожАЛИ друг другу руки*** / ***Побеседовав, они пожимаЮТ друг другу руки*** / ***Побеседовав, они пожМУТ друг другу руки***

Comment: adverbial participles of reflexive verbs are formed with suffixes -(а)ясь for imperfective (and provisionally for perfective) and -вшись for perfective

Comment: Some sources use other terminology. They call those adverbs "gerunds", being the -ая form the present gerund, and the -в form the past gerund.
Делая translates as "doing", while сделав translates as "upon having done", if I understood correctly.

Comment: i think referring to them as perfective - imperfective in contrast to past - present does more justice to their grammatical function